# How do I assign part of a hash to another variable?

Tags: ruby

Trying to assign part of a has to another variable. I have a hash. Something like:

```
hash = {
    "cupcake" => {
        "a" => 1
    },
    "muffin" => {
        "b" => 2
    }
}
```

When I do something like:

```
cupcake = hash["cupcake"]
```

**cupcake** is **nil** after this code.

Comment: That shouldn't work, it's not valid Ruby code.

Comment: I tried your code after the edit in irb and it works fine

Comment: @Ursus Figured out why it wasn't working. Was a bug in other code that created the hash that someone else wrote. I never used ruby before so I thought maybe copying sub-hashes wasn't allowed. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem, I knew this code was fine :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want string keys you have to use this syntax

```
hash = {
    "cupcake" => {
        "a" => 1
    },
    "muffin" => {
        "b" => 2
    }
}
```

Syntax with colons is for symbol keys

```
hash = {
  cupcake: {
    a: 1
  },
  muffin: {
    b: 2
  }
}

cupcake = hash[:cupcake]
```

Comment: Yeah, `"a": 1` and `a: 1` are identical, even though that's counter-intuitive.

Comment: the first block wasn't my actual code, I just wrote it on the spot (in json-like representation to show an example of what I wanted to do. I'll edit original post.